# Проблема адресации массива на ассемблере

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

У меня по заданию надо удалить первый парный элемент массива, я его нахожу запоминаю адрес и потом просто затираю его перемещением элементов и последний элемент обнуляю. Вот код:

```
.586
.Model flat,stdcall
Option casemap:none
.Data
buf dd -10,4,-2,6,8,-1,3,12,-7,5
nx dd 10
.Data?
.code
start:
LEA EBX,buf
CALL find_par
CALL DeleteElem
RET
find_par    PROC
XOR ESI,ESI
MOV ECX,nx
c1:MOV EDX,[EBX+ESI] 
TEST EDX,1
JNZ M1
ADD ESI,4
LOOP c1
M1:
MOV EDI,ESI
RET
find_par ENDP
DeleteElem PROC
MOV ESI,EDI
MOV ECX,nx
SUB ECX,ESI
c1:MOV [EBX+ESI],[EBX+ESI+4]; <--- Проблема тут
LOOP c1
MOV ESI,nx
MOV [EBX+ESI*4],0; <----- и тут
RET
DeleteElem ENDP
end start
```

Выбивает ошибку 2070, как ее исправить

Comment: И что это за ошибка? описание-то у неё есть? Формально - думаю, проблема в том, что не указан размер операнда для копирования...

Comment: Архитектура x86 не позволяет с помощью mov копировать напрямую из памяти в память. Копируйте через регистр (из памяти в регистр, потом из регистра в память), или с помощью команды movs, но тогда в регистрах edi должен лежать адрес куда копировать, в esi - откуда.

Comment: Во втором случае действительно не указан размер операнда (ассемблер не понимает, сколько нужно копировать - байт, слово, двойное слово?)

Comment: @insolor я переделал адресацию таким образом: ` MOVS [EBX+EDI*4],[EBX+ESI*4]`, но у меня выдает ошибку с размером, А2023: instruction operand must have size, где указывать размер?

Comment: У команды movs вообще нет операндов, она просто берет данные по адресу esi и кладет по адресу edi. То как вы хотите ее использовать работать не будет. Ну и чтобы перемещать по 4 байта, нужно использовать вариант команды movsd.

Comment: @insolor Я студент и ассемблер препод мягко говоря плохо преподает. Мне надо найти первый парный и потом удалить его из массива. Я нахожу адрес элемента и потом просто сдвигаю на один элемент, но я не могу устроить правильно адресацию, вернее не понимаю, как правильно это сделать, т.к в методичках у нас нет описания подобных алгоритмов. Можно пример такой адресации, пожалуйста?

Comment: Самый простой вариант я уже описал: двумя командами через промежуточный регистр. Думаю, тут не стоит выдумывать чего-то еще.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо, заработало)